# Xml .NET : Remove ArrayOfXmlElement and XmlElement

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I created a .NET class for XML serialization

```
[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot("documents")]
public class BdfXmlData
{
    [XmlElement("document")]
    public List<XmlElement> Documents { get; set; }

    public BdfXmlData()
    {
        Documents = new List<XmlElement>();
    }
}
```

When I try to serialize an object, I get with this tree:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfXmlElement xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <XmlElement>
    <documents>
      <document>
               ...
      <document>
    <documents>
  </XmlElement>
</ArrayOfXmlElement>
```

How can I have the following three?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<documents>
  <document>
    ...
  <document>
<documents>
```

Thanks in advance.

The code to serialize my class is the following:

```
public static string GetSerializedObject<T>(T t)
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        serializer.Serialize(stream, t);
        stream.Position = 0;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean you want everything between <documents> node?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can at least simplify your xml-code:

```
<ArrayOfdocuments xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <documents>
    <document>
               ...
    <document>
  <documents>
</ArrayOfdocuments>
```

The "XmlElement" element can be left out.

Comment: My Property is "Documents" and the xml tag is "document"

Comment: Do you want to use the "XmlElement" element several times in your xml?

Comment: Yes, I want to have several instance of <document></document> in the root (documents)

Answer (score 0):

Surely you are serialising an array of BdfXmlData

*in pseudo code*

```
BdfXmlData[] dataInArray = new [] {new BdfXmlData()};
GetSerializedObject(dataInArray)
```

would produce what you have whereas,

*in pseudo code*..

```
BdfXmlData data = new BdfXmlData();
GetSerializedObject(data)
```

should give you what you want!

Answer (score 0):

Exact, I serialise the Documents collection :

```
SerializationHelper.GetSerializedObject(xmlRootData.Documents);
```

---

In fact, I receive some XmlElement with this tree :

```
<document>
           ...
<document>
```

and I add these elements to my List "Documents".

```
xmlRootData.Documents.Add(xmlData);
```

When I serialise my final object (BdfXmlData), the xml contains 2 documents tags and 2 document tags

```
string xmlData = SerializationHelper.GetSerializedObject(xmlRootData);
```

---

```
<documents xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <document>
    <documents>
      <document>
      </document>
    <documents>
  </document>
</documents>
```